# How To Spy On An Exported and Mocked Function In Jest

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, tdd, jestjs

I am trying to mock a module (which has an exported function[and this is also mocked]).

I would like to spy on the exported function to check that it was called with something.

This is my code...

```
import { addNewPaymentMethod } from '../src/service'

jest.mock('../src/service', () => ({
  addNewPaymentMethod : (paymentMethodInfoModel) => {
    let responseFromApi = {responseStatus:{name:'blah'}};
    return Promise.resolve(responseFromApi);
  }
}))

import { createNewPaymentMethod } from '../src/actions/paymentMethod'

test('test expect', () => {
  createNewPaymentMethod({owNickName:'nName',id:22})();

  //this is the bit I don't know how to do
  //...
  jest.spyOn(addNewPaymentMethod);
  expect(addNewPaymentMethod).toBeCalledWith({some:object});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the mock using [jest.fn()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestfnimplementation)**.**[mockResolvedValue(value)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvaluevalue)

```
jest.mock('../src/service', () => ({
  addNewPaymentMethod : jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
    responseStatus: {
      name:'blah'
    }
  })
}))
```

and then since it's a jest.fn() you don't need to spyOn it :)
but note that since it's async (uses promises) you either have to chain then to the method (and use return):

```
it('should have been called with data', () => {
  const data = {};
  return service.methodWhichCallsDependencysaddNewPaymentMethod(data).then(() => {
    return expect(addNewPaymentMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
  });
});
```

or use async/await:

```
it('should have been called with data', async () => {
  const data = {};
  await service.methodWhichCallsDependencysaddNewPaymentMethod(data);
  expect(addNewPaymentMethod).toHaveBeenCalledWith(data);
});
```

I've set up [a working example](https://repl.it/repls/CylindricalUncommonPresses)

Comment: The problem is with using 'service' because I haven't got a 'service'. The addNewPaymentMethod is exported as a const from the module (along with other consts like deletePaymentMethod). How do I write your first test to take account of this?